# Why can't I see HDF5 files in my directory when I create them in Python on Windows 10?

Tags: python, file, hdf5, h5py

I've written this code:

```
data_to_write = np.random.random(size=(100,20))

with h5py.File('name-of-file.h5', 'w') as hf:
    hf.create_dataset("name-of-dataset",  data=data_to_write)

with h5py.File('name-of-file.h5', 'r') as hf:
    data = hf['name-of-dataset'][:]
```

However, `name-of-file.h5` doesn't appear in my working directory. This is what I see currently:

[image: Current result]

I would expect to see this:

[image: Expected result]

But I do not. Why?

Comment: Obviously, `name-of-file.h5` exists somewhere. :-) How are you running your Python code? from an IDE? If so, many can run from a different working directory than the location of the source code. Try `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('name-of-file.h5'))` to get the path to your h5 file.

Comment: Thanks that helped me find where they were going... Normally Spyder just saves files in my working directory. This is my first time working with HDF5 files and it's saving in `C:\Users\MyName` for some reason... Why might that be?

Comment: Guess I should have written that as an answer. :) I use Spyder too. The  "Run" folder is user defined. Look in the top right corner for the current value (next to the folder icon), OR go to Tools/Preferences:Run, then look look under Working Directory settings. I use "The directory of the file being executed".